# Melhor lógica para manipulação de planilhas

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Boa tarde caríssimos, estou com um projeto em mãos onde tenho quatro planilhas, uma de cada "programa de gerenciamento de estações de computadores" na qual, em todas elas, tenho uma coluna com o número de patrimônio da máquina.

A grande maioria das máquinas estão nas 4 planilhas, porém algumas não, e esse é meu objetivo. Quero pegar essas 4 planilhas e colocar elas em uma só, onde terei apenas 4 colunas (dos 4 programas) sendo que nas linhas dessas colunas eu quero pôr o número de patrimônio caso ele esteja presente na tabela referente aquela coluna, deixando em branco caso contrário.

Gostaria que essa tabela nova esteja então em ordem crescente de patrimônio sendo que na linha do patrimônio 12345 por exemplo, esteja marcado "12345 - 12345 - - 12345", supondo que ele nao esteja presente apenas na terceira coluna.

Estou usando jexcelapi, porem estou um pouco perdido em COMO fazer esse mapeamento, em ordem e etc. Alguém tem alguma dica? Nâo tenho dúvidas quanto ao código, apenas a lógica de como estruturar esse programa mesmo).

Grato!

Comment: Cara nunca vi jexcelapi. Os dados são armazenados em uma lista?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, cada uma das 4 planilhas têm 1 coluna e várias linhas, e você quer converter isso para 1 planilha com 4 colunas e várias linhas? Se sim, a coluna relevante de cada planilha é a coluna A?

Comment: Por que você está usando Java pra fazer isso? É mais fácil e direto fazer apenas no Excel...

Comment: JexcelApi apenas tem funcoes pra ler e escrever e manipular, guardo onde eu quiser.

Comment: E sim, tenho 4 tabelas com uma coluna de "chave primaria" igual em todas, quero transformar em uma tabela com apenas essas 4 colunas. Quero usar essa tabela pra facilmente conferir qual maquina não está presente em alguma das tabelas